# PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on my script

Tags: php, foreach

Hi I am getting this errors in my php scipt :

**error number 1.** 
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/tsbt/public_html/index.php on line 231

the code is :

```
 <?php
        foreach ($result as $lang) {
  ?>       <option value="<?php echo $lang['code'] ?>"><?php echo $lang['name']; ?></option>
 <?php
```

**error numner 2.**
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:

```
case SRT_STATE_TEXT:
                     if (trim($line) == '') {
                         $sub = new stdClass;
                         $sub->number = $subNum;
                         list($sub->startTime, $sub->stopTime) = explode(' --> ', $subTime);
                         $sub->text   = $subText;
                         $subText     = '';
                         $state       = SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER;

                         $subs[]      = $sub;
                     } else {
```

Comment: is $result an array? what var_dump($result) says?

Comment: show us what `$result` is.

Comment: you're missing a brace here also, if that's your actual code.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you didnt supply an array or anything else you could iterate throuhg.

put before that foreach this line

```
var_dump($result);
```

and you will see it is not an array or object. - probably null, or string. You need to pass an array or object you could iterate through.

Answer (score -1):

**error number 1**

Use `is_array` check before `foreach`: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-array.php to avoid such error.

**error number 2**

Check what in `$subTime`. It could be the case that ' --> ' isn't there. As result it couldn't be exploded:

```
explode(' --> ', $subTime)
```